# Regex split by multiple look ahead words

Tags: jquery, regex

Using jQuery I want to split a string by multiple words without removing them.

I currently have:

```
var mystring = "one banana apple two carrot bean three chicken beef"
var mySplit = mystring.split(/one|two|three/);
```

But this removes the split words. How do I split immediately before these words?

Output I want is:

```
"one banana apple", "two carrot bean", "three chicken beef"
```

Comment: Why jQuery - a library for DOM manipulation?

Comment: @Mikey Because I am manipulating the DOM using the string?

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with jQuery.

Comment: @Mikey I am using Regex in jQuery. If I don't mention this, I will be asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this one

`\W(?=one\s|two\s|three\s)`

**Explanation**

`\W` a non-word character

`(?=...)` followed by

`one\s|two\s|three\s` *one*, *two* or *three* then a whitespace (this will prevent *onexxx*, *twoxxx* or *threexxx* to be matched

```js
var mystring = "one banana apple two carrot bean three threexxx"
var mySplit = mystring.split(/\W(?=one\s|two\s|three\s)/);

console.log(mySplit);
```